# Application to organize / manage installed networks

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, organizer

I was wondering if there is a Application where you can organize networks. I mean if you have installed some networks you have to note every pc's name, his ip-address and so on.

Is there a Application where you can manage it?

---

I saw the monitoring tools but that is not exactly what I'm looking for. Maybe I didnt explain me well, after all my englis his not so good :)

For example if I install many different networks I write in a book how I configured them. I write pc-name ip-address ip-gateway ip-broadcast and so on for each network.

It will be great if I can do it in a program to organize it well, and for example it gives me a node view of the network.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a network monitoring tool that comes together with an „inventory” feature.

I am using [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) for monitoring all computers from a network and in Zabbix you can create a profile for each computer when you can add the mac address and various other information. Maybe Zabbix is a bit to much for your needs.

You can also try GLPI Project http://www.glpi-project.org/?lang=en ... I am not sure it is is also to complex for your needs or look at this project http://www.open-audit.org/about.php

Comment: Ok I'l check  them.
I'm not only searching a tool for my own network, I mean I want to note networks i'm the manager so that I can organize them and I can know in a simple way characteristics without seeing in the pc.

Comment: To know the 'inside' of a compter without opening it you can try using lshw - http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter. It also has a GUI http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter/GUI

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need an IPAM application along the lines of Infoblox.  The only free (GPL) alternative I could find is [this tool, called IPplan](http://iptrack.sourceforge.net/).

It allows for a spreadsheet-like view of a subnet, listing nodes automatically (and querying via SNMP if desired) and allows for individual nodes to be edited for additional information.